Why does flex: 0; override the width property?
This is my first year teaching web design, and we are covering flexbox layout. I have run into a glitch with the flex property that I cannot find an explanation for anywhere.
I have reviewed this using a wide range of resources and all indicated that setting flex to 0 is the same as setting it to flex: 0, 0, auto. In this case, auto will use a flex item's width property as its flex-basis value.  However, I am finding this to not be true. When using the shorthand method (as most of these resources suggest) of flex:0, this overrides my width value.
Here is the HTML:
<nav id="menu">

    <div id="Item1" class="menuitem">Item 1</div>
    <div id="Item2" class="menuitem">Item 2</div>
    <div id="Item3" class="menuitem">Item 3</div>
    <div id="Item4" class="menuitem">Item 4</div>
    <div id="Item5" class="menuitem">Item 5</div>

</nav>

Here is the pertinent CSS:
.menuitem { width: 120px;
            padding: 3px; 
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 16pt;
            font-weight: bold;
            flex: 0;
            }

This is what I expected to happen from what I have researched (Flexbox row using flex: 0, 0, auto;):

However, here is the result I get (Flexbox row using flex:0;):

When I use the longer version, flex: 0, 0, auto;, all of my items are sized properly.
Curious to see if anyone has an explanation for why this would be occurring that I could pass along to my students.

Please note that the initial  tag is present in my code. It was left out of the code example.

When you set flex: 0; you're omitting the flex-shrink and flex-basis components. The relevant part of the spec says:

<‘flex-shrink’>
[...] When omitted, it is set to 1.
<‘flex-basis’>
[...] When omitted from the flex shorthand, its specified value is 0.

So flex: 0; is equivalent to flex: 0 1 0; which is why you're seeing the elements shrink/not use their main size (width).
What you're probably looking for is flex: none; which is equivalent to flex: 0 0 auto;.
Here's a snippet using flex: none;:


#menu { display: flex; }
.menuitem { width: 120px;
            padding: 3px; 
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 16pt;
            font-weight: bold;
            flex: none;
            }
<nav id="menu">

    <div id="Item1" class="menuitem">Item 1</div>
    <div id="Item2" class="menuitem">Item 2</div>
    <div id="Item3" class="menuitem">Item 3</div>
    <div id="Item4" class="menuitem">Item 4</div>
    <div id="Item5" class="menuitem">Item 5</div>

</nav>



To make this really explicit, it's actually in the spec a second time:

flex: <positive-number>
Equivalent to flex: <positive-number> 1 0. Makes the flex item flexible and sets the flex basis to zero, resulting in an item that receives the specified proportion of the free space in the flex container. If all items in the flex container use this pattern, their sizes will be proportional to the specified flex factor.


Thank you for that explanation, which makes sense.  I must have read something incorrectly somewhere.  This shows me that I need to review the values of none and initial for flex.

I find there's a lot of hearsay about defaults that may or may not be accurate. W3C specs are my go-to for answers when I see behavior that doesn't match what I'm expecting based on other sources.
